# File not found in project when parsing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to parse `HTML` with `JSOUP library` from local file. But my IDE can't find this file.

Project structure:

```
- ParsingHTML
- .idea
- files
-    index.html
-    login.html
- libs
- out
- src
-    Parsing.java
```

Here is my code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Parsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File input = new File("./../files/index.html");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "https://jsoup.com/");
            System.out.println(doc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How I can fix it?

P.S.:
Change directory name from `file` to `files` and file from "input" to "index".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because this location not exist.
Try to use:

```
File input = new File("files/input.html");
```

or

```
Path input = Paths.get("files","input.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Parsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
           final File input = new File(dir +"/files/input.html");
           final  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "https://jsoup.com/");
            System.out.println(doc.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your project structure tells is that yours "input.html" file doesn't exist, so the error is correct. Maybe you ctrl+c ctrl+v the Jsoup example without changing the html file's name.
Also check:

> new File("./../files/input.html");

In your project the folder name is file, not file**s**.